# I want to display a table of metrics but unable to do so

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

i am developing a plugin that calculates the class metrics of the selected java file.
so, m using IWorkbenchWindowAction delegate to add the plugin button and menu option.

by selecting the java file, and clicking on the plugin button,
i obtain the pathname of the selected file, and now
i need to calculate the metrics over it.

suppose i have already calculated the metrics.
now, i want to display them in tabular form.

what needs to be done ???
how can i display a table , and display it as soon as the plugin button is pressed (after calculating the metrics, ofcourse).. ??

Answer (score 0):

You must probably create your own view, with table (Viewer) inside it. Updating viewer strategy can be different. For instance, you can make your view listen to some events, which are generated after the metrics are calculated. Or, if you want to have a separate button for updating the view, then you should attach proper action/command handler with necessary logic. Does this answer your question, or I am missing something?

Comment: okkkkk, i understand this.. its just the interaction between the java files for Metric Calculation and View, thats hard to grasp. how can one do that ? interact like that ?     since, the metricaction java file gets executed on pressing the plugin button. and also, since it is also passing some data to the View java file..

Comment: I have somehow managed to create a view, in the same class. But i am still green , as to how to link the view with the action delagate. i want to display the output on view, as soon as i click the button. and if i then select another file, and click on the button again, i want the view to display the calculated contents for the new selected file (updation ?? ) .. Please help me out in this.

Comment: Also, its not like i want the view to display something depending on the metric calculations.. i want to display the metrics themselves.. how do i pass the metric values to the view, thats troublesome.. :/

Comment: For checking out which file was selected you can take a look at ISelectionListener. There are also a lot of information in the Internet about this. Take a look at this for instance: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecllink/?ca=dgr-lnxw03EclipseGUIviews, www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html ("Integration with other views" chapter). Regarding your last question: you can wrap your metrics data into the object in display it afterwards (as it is usually done in OOP I suppose;))

Comment: i would wrap up the metrics into an object. bt passing the object on for view to display is the point.  also, the integration is with other views, and not with the Iworkbenchwindowaction delegate,  and i have already retrieved the filename using icompilationunit, in iworkbenchwindowaction delegate.   now all i want to know, is how to send the data object to the view for display, or any other way.